# How do I make a powerset from an arbitrary set in python?

Tags: python, set

I had a lab today about making a power set from a set of arbitrary size, but I couldn't seem to think of the best way to do it. No one in the class has done Python before either. Only done java

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I would recommend looking at the itertools module.

Comment: maybe you could team up with your classmate here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19308021/17875  ;)

Answer (score 3):

There's a recipe in [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for that:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Comment: +1, `from itertools import chain, combinations` in case that isn't obvious.

Comment: Well, let's just say I'm an idiot. This code below is what I have now. She wants us to input a set and output a set of frozensets that represents the powerset. I'm not expressly looking for an answer, maybe just a point in the right direction.


`def powerset(s):
 list = []
 result = set()
 for element in (s):
  list.append(s.pop)
 for i in range (0, len(list)-1):
  temp1 = list[i:len(list)-2]
  temp2 = list[i+1:len(list)-1]
  temp = list.pop(i)
"""
  result.add(frozenset([temp]))
  result.add(frozenset([temp1]))
  result.add(frozenset([temp2]))
"""
 return result`

Comment: @user2869097 If you want to do all this manually, you'll need a method like `combinations` and then you can call that method to create combinations of `n` elements for `n` from 0 to the length of the set. I'm sure you can find a pure Python `combinations`-like method online.

Comment: Who is "she", @user2869097?

Answer (score 0):

The insight is that for each set S in the powerset, a given member of the original set is either in S or it isn't. Since this is a binary decision, the powerset doubles for each additional element in the original set.

```
powerset({a}) = {{}, {a}}

powerset({a,b}) = {{}, {a}, {b}, {a,b}}

powerset({a,b,c}) = union(
                       powerset({a,b}),
                       union({c}, X) where X in powerset({a,b})
                    )
```

This leads to a nice recursive algorithm that works for sets of "arbitrary size" as long as arbitrary is not too large.