# Output Set and Its Contents in Python?

Tags: python, set

I am merely wanting to output the contents of a `set` (because I *have* to use this cursed and inflexible type), but every time I go to do it or loop through and print each element, I get the last one instead of the rest. Here's my entire code:

```python
def factorial(n):
    r = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        r *= i
    return r

def nCr(n, r):
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(r) * factorial(n - r))

def combinations(s, tokens):
    maxcombos = int(nCr(len(s), tokens))
    for index in range(maxcombos):
        token_copy = tokens
        combo = []
        for val in range(1, len(s) + 1):
            if not token_copy:
                break
            thresh = nCr(len(s) - val, token_copy - 1)
            if index < thresh:
                combo.append(s.pop())
                token_copy -= 1
            else:
                index -= thresh
        yield tuple(combo)

def powerset(s):
    pset = set()
    for num_tokens in range(1, len(s)):
        for combo in combinations(s, num_tokens):
            pset.add(combo)
    pset.update(s)
    #pset.update(tuple())
    return pset

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = set([1,2,23])
    p = powerset(s)
    msg = "Initial set: set(["
    for (i, item) in enumerate(s):
        msg += str(item) + ", "
    msg += "])"
    print(msg)
    #print(powerset())
```

I merely want each one to appear in between those `([])` like a normal set does. Is there a way to simply output the whole variable with its contents? Thanks!

Comment: repr(myset) not working for you?

Comment: No. Thanks, but I actually figured it out.

Comment: Cursed and inflexible? Sets are *amazing* and *powerful*. You will miss them horribly in languages that don't have them.

Comment: @kojiro: Or you'll just build them in 5 minutes out of a `dict`, in languages that have `dict` but not `set` (as 50% of all Python projects did before 2.3).

Comment: Meanwhile… why are you using `for (i, item) in enumerate(s):` when you're never using `i` inside the loop? For that matter, why not just replace the whole loop with a `', '.join` call? It almost seems like you're going out of your way to make things harder just so you can complain about it. That's obviously not true, but the fact that your code _looks_ that way means maybe you need to spend more time refactoring and simplifying and less time just hammering on bits of it until they seem to work.

Comment: @abarnert You know very well using a dict or hashmap isn't even close to the same thing. You lose the expressive power of all the actual set operators, have to manually implement what you need as methods or functions, it's bound to be slower and more annoying to read, you have to maintain a garbage value which might be falsy, and typecasting sucks.

Comment: @kojiro: Why would it be more annoying to read? You know you can define classes in Python, and overload operators for them? Using it reads _exactly_ like using a native set (well, no set comprehensions… but 2.3-2.6 didn't have those either). And what's stopping you from building the set operators? And why would it be significantly slower? The cost of increfing the dummy value for each lookup is nothing. You can find Alex Martelli's and Greg Wilson's early `sets` modules if you want; they're about 200 lines of dead-simple code that give you pretty much the same API you have today.

Comment: @abarnert my point was about modern languages that don't have them, like most of the JavaScript in use today. Not about old versions of Python.

Comment: Also, while it's only tangentially relevant to this question - you'll have a better time with Python if you get in the habit of checking the standard library for core functions like `factorial` and `combinations`. `combinations` can be found in the `itertools` module, which is admittedly something of an advanced topic. As of 2.6, `math.factorial` exists and will certainly be faster than the naive algorithm you have here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.factorial . In some cases it would be worth profiling a memoized Python version against it, but this implementation is slow.

Comment: @kojiro: I actually built a Set prototype for a JS project just a few months ago. The interface isn't quite as nice as Python, but then JS Object isn't as nice as Python dict either. Really, in almost any language where you're missing set but have a dict equivalent, just build it yourself.

Comment: @abarnert I really wasn't saying it's impossible to create a Set type, but there's no substitute for native support.

Answer (score 2):

Your `powerset` function actually alters its input.  In `combinations`, you use `s.pop()`. That's almost certainly wrong, and would explain why its contents have changed when you try to print it.

The simplest fix is to replace your `powerset` function with the recipe from the `itertools` documentation:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
def powerset(input_set):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(input_set)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Comment: and this is why you use `frozenset` if you don't intend to update the set later  :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the top of your combinations definition to the following:

```
def combinations(r, tokens):
    s = set(r)
    # everything else you had
```

This creates a new set which will not be altered in the combinations function. The reason it was being altered before is because the local variable in combinations was a reference to the same object outside the function. If two names reference the same object, mutating one will affect the other.

In main you want the following:

```
for (i, item) in enumerate(s):
    msg += str(item) + ", "
msg = msg[:-2]
msg += "])"
```